# Deep Replace Object type with Other Object Type if key is present

Tags: typescript

How can i replace all properties of `B` with the values of `A`? and omit all keys of `A` that are not in `B`.

```
type A = {
  a: {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: boolean
    d: {
      a: any
      b: any
    }
  }
  b: { b: null }

}
type B = {
  a: {
    a: boolean
    b: boolean
    d: { a: boolean }
  }
}
// Result
type C = {
  a: {
    a: string
    b: number
    d: { a: any }
  }
}
```

Edit:

Here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgEoIDYEMDGEA8AVANFAKoB8UAvFLlBAB7AQB2AJgM5QD2ARgFYQbAoAfmI16TNp179BQgFBQoAbygBtANJQAloygBrCCA4AzKgF0AXFE10GLdgaOmiw2PCSpMOXBrOEivmRWPupmUAC+UFYu0XJxoJBQAPIAbhAATulazDgAyhwArulYhLho6QDmEMBklPlFWGJ2ktx8Aq5KCmqaOvqGJlD1xRCW1k0SDv2mZZXVrqkZWTnYQ1i+peVVwIFRg4XDvgDccpHBm9XH8eDQAIoFGSBJvHi1VOP2Um2yyl0ahtq6RwDXBmIRWO4PJ48PB-EBmEjHU5QAByHEYyIKKHQXBQ3jItgmnxkrkYEDS6V2XA4HFxaEYlzkCWgAHFEABBAAKAAkAPo3AAyPNwAE0OQBRCg-RTZKysYBZRgVfBdRhoAC2EFl8p0Sq6bNYrGqrDBUsU2gYatYVgAFJ0zWaZVA5QrdfbFKqNVqXcr7ZEAJSqPxdSLK8IM4wFRgCLRoqAAR3u6RA2AhSfeklTj2erM5vIFQtFYpIJGtCYe4MTID9poA9DXYBwIKxGAByQQAdw46T0XXS1SKuiUkTQ7AWmWyOEzhBz3L5gpF4pIXTrUAA6l29Kxl-W+8AB8ph+w4AhkGB0FgU5Xp+zZ-mF0WTnEMGi5VA++xKGWk7aVerNVB5XuH1tGYKxAIgYD9UNYArVNaULVg1QuntO03XdP8wPSIDkLdR1wOA30cLMYMTj9J8X0EPtMGAXJgDQBgrBnPN50LSV3yAA) why @catgirlkelly answer doesn't work in my case.

```
type DeepReplace<T, U> = T extends object ? U extends object ?
  { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof U ? DeepReplace<T[K], U[K]> : T[K] } : U : U


type Override<Source, Target> = Source extends object ? {
  [K in keyof Source]: K extends keyof Target ? Override<Source[K], Target[K]> : Source[K];
} : Target;


type QueryObj<T> = T extends object ? {
  [Key in keyof T]?: QueryObj<T[Key]>;
} : NonNullable<T> extends object ? never : boolean;


type GRAPH_QL_TYPE = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  Assets?: {
    items: ({
      id: string,
      name: string,
    } )[],
  } ,
};


function query<Query extends QueryObj<GRAPH_QL_TYPE>>(query: Query) {
  // Doesn't work
  return {} as Override<Query, GRAPH_QL_TYPE>
  // Works
  // return {} as DeepReplace<Query, GRAPH_QL_TYPE>
}

const res = query({
  name: true,
  id: true,
  Assets: {
    items: [
      {
        name: true,
        id: true,
      }
    ]
  }
})
// res.Assets.items[0].name = true with Override, and it equals string with DeepReplace
const reactState: GRAPH_QL_TYPE = res
```

Comment: Write some code that does that?  I assume you know how to create objects, assign properties from one object to another, examine the keys of an object's properties, and use `if` statements to determine if a key from one object is present in another.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are asking to do this at the type level, which is possible like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOPOdN). If this is acceptable for you, Syler, I will write up an answer.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is a code question or a type question, questions on SO should show at least a minimal effort of trying to solve the problem themselves. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: This kind of deep object type processing always seems to come with 1,000 edge cases.  Optional properties, extra keys, missing keys, unions, etc.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLlpVm) meet your needs?  Please test against any use cases you care about and if you see a problem, then [edit] the question to show the requirement.  Otherwise I can write up an answer.

Comment: @catgirlkelly yes exatly that, ive been trying all day to do that.

Comment: Is it really as simple as this, though? What about the points jcalz brought up?

Comment: @catgirlkelly Yeah I don't want to touch this until someone has examined edge cases.  I've been burned a few too many times where I write up a whole thing and then they reply "this is almost perfect!  One tiiiiny little problem, though is that it needs to output optional properties every third Wednesday" which requires a complete refactoring to achieve.

Comment: @jcalz looks good, but ill test it a bit more to be sure, ill write you again in 10min ish.

Comment: @jcalz thanks a lot it, im pretty sure it solves my issue, should i edit my question and paste the answer or do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Does the suggestion from @catgirlkelly also work?  Then they can write up an answer if they want since they posted a but before me.  If they don't want to then I'd be happy to do it.  If you do decide to answer it yourself (which is [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) you should post it as an answer and not just edit the question.

Comment: the suggestion from @catgirlkelly does not work in my case, not sure why, their answer does technically answer the question, maybe it would solve someone elses problem, if you don't write an answer i will write one and credit you,  its up to you.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to show an example where it makes a difference?  If you have a requirement, it should be in the question.

Comment: @jcalz i added an example.

Comment: Mine doesn't work because it's supposed to be `Override<GRAPH_QL_TYPE, Query>`. To be fair I did name my parameters in an ambiguous way :p

Comment: So then @catgirlkelly’s answer *does* work and maybe they should write the answer.

Comment: if i swap the arguments all values get set to true, which is not that helpful, try it in the playground and see for yourself.

Comment: o_O Ok I see now. These are the kinds of edge cases jcalz mentioned. There's optional properties and arrays which my solution does not cover. The way to solve this is checking if `Target` is also an object, but then that's just a copy of jcalz's answer.

Comment: All right I'll write something up when I get a chance, might be a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sorts of deep object type transformations tend to have lots of edge cases (like [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), and [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types))  so anyone who comes along with the "same" question should take care to test any  answers very carefully.  Here's one possible approach:

```
type DeepReplace<T, U> =
  T extends object ? U extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof U ? DeepReplace<T[K], U[K]> : T[K]
  } : U : U
```

`DeepReplace<T, U>` [recursively](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) replaces (pieces of) `T` with (pieces of) `U`.

If either `T` or `U` are not objects, then `U` is returned as-is.  This is a judgment call and a probable edge case: when one of `T` or `U` is an object and the other is not, it's not 100% clear what the "right" behavior is.

Otherwise we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T` so that any property key `K` that's also found in `U` will cause the property of `T` to be `DeepReplace`d with the corresponding property from `U`.  This is the "core" of `DeepReplace<T, U>` and is probably going to be found in most implementations.

If there are any property keys of `T` that are *not* found in `U`, that property just stays the same and is not replaced.  This is another judgment call and a probable edge case as well.

---

Anyway, let's test it on your example code:

```
type C = DeepReplace<B, A>
/* type C = {
    a: {
        a: string;
        b: number;
        d: {
            a: any;
        };
    };
} */
```

So this works as desired, hooray!  And apparently it also works for your other use case:

```
type Query = {
  name: true;
  id: true;
  Assets: {
    items: {
      name: true;
      id: true;
    }[];
  };
};

type GraphQLType = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  Assets?: {
    items: ({
      id: string,
      name: string,
    })[],
  },
};

type QueryResult = DeepReplace<Query, GraphQLType>
/* type QueryResult = {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    Assets: {
        items: {
            name: string;
            id: string;
        }[];
    } | undefined;
} */
```

Double hooray.  The exact desired types around optional properties and unions with `undefined` are not 100% obvious to me, but again, this depends on the particulars of the use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXM9mmuUAzsAE4CWAdgOYGEBGe1ArgLaMTkOYDGeRgHshAGwhZqvKABM8qDISJ5JIaZmbZqaxZgC+DA4s1IomtqNFQj6G2lCQoAIQT5FxBUuLCxEqbrNBEXFJaTlkbCDfSWtDW3R0B2gAEQgIMAAldNEsPggAHgAVABooAFUAPgQGQqgIAA9gCGoZEighRgArCD5gKAB+crrG5tb2rp6+wc9CAG0AaSgaKABrCBAhADMoQoBdPEWGppa2tY3tsoGoVPSssBy8ooXd0rLnqrxC58MoPEu-hL2cDQADCrhumWyuQKTlKMAq6AA9AAqKBJKBgxAzZRuJRePBkKh0ADc6iYLA4XHIpICSnC2Lx+K0IBpjP0rMIehpeigyMRgMB6IAiqxuCBXDNqFh2BA8BRRRzKOF5RAOTASCQIMASPJpJQmuwdbi8VKZXLyAqyUrzZaAnpZrsOVzbDTEsCoABxchYMAACyFABlCu6sQxraQKDRaMUGKbZRGidGGOrNdr+rqAvqIIa8AAKBmYcOEqMx2lQOMEyN0UtKPQASgdNespedaDdjhFYqyJFYoj6iAhdweBU75BApS9Pv9QeBCLQKLR7tHIG7vf7xswFYTUY5hfCxZJ0hTWqNBcIWZzG7Zm+l8YPtF316W+6rD7J+gdj55AB8oKwWhAmw0BAMjcryiJAA)